# Flask wtf-form not validating after I add default values?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

Flask Wtf Form no longer validates on submit after I add `form.field.default = value` and then `form.process()`

For example my form class,

```
class SelectFoo(FlaskForm):
    var1 = SelectField('Var 1')
    var2 = SelectField('Var 2')
    var3 = SelectField('Var 3')
```

My Route,

```
@route.route('/foo-input', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo_route():
    form = SelectFoo()
    df = pd.Dataframe({'var_1': np.random.rand(10), 'var_2': np.random.rand(10), 'var_3': np.random.rand(10)})
    choices = [(s, s.replace('_', ' ').title()) for s in df.columns]
    fuzzy_lookup = compare_lists(target, cols)
    print(fuzzy_lookup) # for this test use {i:i for i in df.columns}
    print(choices)

    form.val1.choices = choices
    form.val2.choices = choices
    form.val2.choices = choices

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        dict_ = {
            'var 1': form.var1.data,
            'var 2': form.var2.data,
            'var 3': form.var2.data,
        }
        return jsonify(dict_)
    return render_template('footemplate.html', form=form)
```

If I add,

```
@route.route('/foo-input', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo_route():
    ...
    form.coupon.choices = choices

    form.val1.default = fuzzy_lookup['val1']
    form.val2.default = fuzzy_lookup['val2']
    form.val2.default = fuzzy_lookup['val2']
    form.process()

    ...
        return jsonify(dict_)
    return render_template('footemplate.html', form=form)
```

The form will render with the selected value that is with `default. However, my form no longer submits, best I can tell is that it adds a`selected`keyword to an option`Val 1` when I add the default option in my html form. I did a complete diff of the html and that is all I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to process the form in the 'GET' request.

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form.process()
```

Then everything works fine.